# Cannot read property 'getThreads' of null

Tags: gmail, google-apps-script

I have this code, and I'm not getting why the `getThreads` property is not being read.

Is `getThreads()` deprecated or so?

```
function cleanUp() {  
var delayDays = 2 // Enter # of days before messages are moved to trash   
var maxDate = new Date(); 
maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate()-delayDays);    
var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("2dehands");  
var threads = label.getThreads() || [];  
for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {  
  if (threads[i].getLastMessageDate()<maxDate)
  {  
    threads[i].moveToTrash();
  } 
} 
}
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getThreads' of null
> cleanUp   @ Code.gs:6

Answer (score 1):

The error means that the value/object referenced by `label` is `null`. Check if there is a label named `2dehands` in the user Gmail mailbox.

Comment: there is, but as a sub-label named cleanup.. I thought it queried every label, also sublabels.

Comment: The format for "sub-labels" is `Parent Label/Sub Label`